# Multiplying column value by another value depending on value in certain column R

Tags: r, rows, dplyr

in the following dataset, I would like to multiply value in column `Size` by value in column `Month1`, `Month2` or `Month3` depending on what number we have in column `Month`. So if in certain row the `Month` value is 2, I would like to multiply the value in column `Size` by the value in column `Month2` and save the result in new column `NewSize`. Many thanks for your help in advance!

```
Orig = c("A","B","A","A","B","A","A","B","A")
Dest = c("B","A","C","B","A","C","B","A","C")
Month = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
Size = c(30,20,10,10,20,20,30,50,20)
Month1 = c(1,0.2,0,1,0.2,0,1,0.2,0)
Month2 = c(0.6,1,0,0.6,1,0,0.6,1,0)
Month3 = c(0,1,0.6,0,1,0.6,0,1,0.6)
df <- data.frame(Orig,Dest,Month,Size,Month1,Month2,Month3)
df

  Orig Dest Month Size Month1 Month2 Month3
1    A    B     1   30    1.0    0.6    0.0
2    B    A     1   20    0.2    1.0    1.0
3    A    C     1   10    0.0    0.0    0.6
4    A    B     2   10    1.0    0.6    0.0
5    B    A     2   20    0.2    1.0    1.0
6    A    C     2   20    0.0    0.0    0.6
7    A    B     3   30    1.0    0.6    0.0
8    B    A     3   50    0.2    1.0    1.0
9    A    C     3   20    0.0    0.0    0.6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one alternative using `ifelse`

```
> transform(df, NewSize=ifelse(Month==1, Size*Month1, 
                  ifelse(Month==2, Size*Month2, Size*Month3)))
  Orig Dest Month Size Month1 Month2 Month3 NewSize
1    A    B     1   30    1.0    0.6    0.0      30
2    B    A     1   20    0.2    1.0    1.0       4
3    A    C     1   10    0.0    0.0    0.6       0
4    A    B     2   10    1.0    0.6    0.0       6
5    B    A     2   20    0.2    1.0    1.0      20
6    A    C     2   20    0.0    0.0    0.6       0
7    A    B     3   30    1.0    0.6    0.0       0
8    B    A     3   50    0.2    1.0    1.0      50
9    A    C     3   20    0.0    0.0    0.6      12
```

Answer (score 3):

In base R, fully vectorized:

```
 df$Size*df[,5:7][cbind(1:nrow(df),df$Month)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd handle this using `data.table`.

```
require(data.table)
setkey(setDT(df), 
      Month)[.(mon = 1:3),                          ## i
      NewSize := Size * get(paste0("Month", mon)),  ## j
      by=.EACHI]                                    ## by
```

- `setDT` converts `df` from *data.frame* to *data.table* by reference.
- `setkey` reorders that *data.table* by the column specified, `Month`, in increasing order, and marks that column as *key* column, on which we'll perform a join.
- We perform a join on the key column set in the previous set with the values `1:3`. This can also be interpreted as a *subset* operation that extracts all rows matching `1,2 and 3` from the key column `Month`.
- So, for each value of `1:3`, we calculate the matching rows in `i`. And on those matching rows, we compute `NewSize` by extracting `Size` and `MonthX` for those matching rows, and multiplying them. We use `get()` to achieve extracting the right `MonthX` column.
- `by=.EACHI` as the name implies, executes the expression in `j` for each `i`. As an example, `i=1` matches (or joins) to rows 1:3 of `df`. For those rows, the j-expression extracts `Size = 30,20,10` and `Month1 = 1.0, 0.2, 0.0`, and it gets evaluated to return `30, 4, 0`. And then for `i=2` and so on..

Hope this helps a bit even if you're looking for a `dplyr` only answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply`:

```
apply(df, 1, function(u) as.numeric(u[paste0('Month', u['Month'])])*as.numeric(u['Size']))
#[1] 30  4  0  6 20  0  0 50 12
```

Or a vectorized solution:

```
bool = matrix(rep(df$Month, each=3)==rep(1:3, nrow(df)), byrow=T, ncol=3)

df[c('Month1', 'Month2', 'Month3')][bool] * df$Size
#[1] 30  4  0  6 20  0  0 50 12
```